# Get Cloud Service Name in a Web Role

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-worker-roles, azure-cloud-services

We have a requirement of logging Cloud Service Name where Web Role is deployed.
We are getting Role Name & Role Instance Id from RoleEnvironment class in Azure ServiceRuntime library.
But not finding Cloud Service Name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't find this information via `RoleEnvironment` class. You would need to use `Service Management API` for that purpose. Basically the trick is to get the deployment id from `RoleEnvironment` class and then invoke Service Management API operations to

- First list the cloud services in the subscription
- Then iterate over each cloud service to get its deployment properties.
- Find the one with matching deployment id.

That would give you the information you need.

To invoke Service Management API operations, you could use [`Azure Management Library`](http://www.bradygaster.com/post/getting-started-with-the-windows-azure-management-libraries) or write your own REST wrapper. I did a blog post long ago where I did similar thing using REST API: http://gauravmantri.com/2012/03/16/programmatically-finding-deployment-slot-from-code-running-in-windows-azure/.